# Discord.js : TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles, member, mention

I am having trouble with getting the right information from message.mentions.roles.first() and message.mentions.members.first()

This is my command handler in Index.js

```
bot.on('message', async (message, guild, helpList, roles) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || !message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ') ;
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const aRole = message.mentions.roles.first();
    const Role = aRole.id
    const name = args.join(' ');
    const User = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!Role && command !== 'create' && command !== 'give' && command !== 'take' && command !== 'help' && command !== 'list') {return message.channel.send('Sorry, that role was not found.')}
    if (!User && (command == 'give' || command == 'take') ) {return message.reply ("That name doesnt match a user.");}

    try{
      bot.commands.get(command).execute(message, Role, name, User, guild, helpList);
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }  

});

      bot.commands.get(command).execute(message, Role, name, User, guild, helpList);
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }  

});
```

Here is my take.js, a command to remove a role from the specified member.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'take',
    description: '',
  execute(message, Role, User, roles){ 
     try{
    User.roles.remove(Role);
        return message.channel.send (`${Role} has been removed from  ${User}'s list of rolls.`);
      }catch(e){
          console.log(e);
          console.log(Role)
          console.log(User)
      }}}
```

This is the error I get.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/commands/take.js:6:16)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/index.js:34:33)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:437:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:294:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/mnt/c/Users/bgera/OneDrive/Desktop/BOTT/RoleBot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
711442214043254854
<@&711442214043254854> <@!271438275619586062>
```

Why is Role not working? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in your code when you call `execute` function here

```js
bot.commands.get(command).execute(message, Role, name, User, guild, helpList);
```

The `execute` function in `take.js` will wait for these parameters :

- *[parameter] => [variable type received]*
- message => [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)
- Role => String (id of the [Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) mentionned)
- User => **String** *(not [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) as intended)*
- guild => undefined
- helpList => undefined

In fact, in the order you give parameters to the `execute` function, you are giving the variable `name` and not `User`. So instead of `User` being a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) it's a String and of course `String.roles` is `undefined`, that's why the error says `cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`.

To fix your error you should modify

```js
bot.commands.get(command).execute(message, Role, name, User, guild, helpList);
```

to

```js
bot.commands.get(command).execute(message, Role, User, name, guild, helpList);
```

(Look closely, I inverted `name` parameter with `User` parameter)

**But wait, it's not finished**

Another issue in your code is that you are declaring too much parameters.

`bot.on("message", callback(Message))` will only call `callback()` with one parameter ([see docs here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message)).

`guild, helpList, roles` are always `undefined` as parameters here.

So you should remove unnecessary parameters like that :

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    ...
}
```

And same for `execute` function call, remove unused parameters :

```js
bot.commands.get(command).execute(message, Role, User);
```

I think that's it. I hope I've been understandable :D

Comment: This helped me a bunch thank you. The order of parameters had not crossed my mind. I am now running into the problem of turning Roll[] into Roll to edit color and add permissions. Ill make a new post if I cant figure it out.

Comment: You're most welcome! Good luck for your other issue.